# SQL count e sum

Tags: sql

Tenho 6 códigos SQL e todos fazem busca na mesma tabela, ela é parecida com essa:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  1  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  |  2  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  4  |  1  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  5  |  1  |  4  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  6  |  1  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  7  |  9  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  8  |  3  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

E os códigos são esses:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(C) as soma FROM tabela WHERE B = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total1 FROM tabela WHERE B = 1 AND C = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total2 FROM tabela WHERE B = 1 AND C = 2;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total3 FROM tabela WHERE B = 1 AND C = 3;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total4 FROM tabela WHERE B = 1 AND C = 4;
SELECT COUNT(*) as total5 FROM tabela WHERE B = 1 AND C = 5;
```

Os valores retornados são esses:

```
total = 4
total1 = 2
total2 = 0
total3 = 0
total4 = 1
total5 = 2
soma = 16
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas precisaria que tudo retornasse na mesma consulta, é possível?

A intenção é ele contar quantas linhas tem na tabela, cujo a coluna B é igual a um valor, então retornar em "total" e somar todos os valores da coluna C e retornar em "soma", mas preciso que ele retorne a quantidade de vezes que um valor se repete na pesquisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que você precisa é algo dessa maneira:

```
select 
count(*) total,
sum(c) soma,
sum(case when C = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Tot1,
sum(case when C = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Tot2,
sum(case when C = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Tot3
from tabela
where B = 1
```

As projeções no formato `sum(case when CONDICAO THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` são muito úteis para esse tipo de cenário. Na CONDICAO você deve colocar algo que seja avaliado para Verdadeiro ou Falso. Nesse caso, você está testando C = 1, 2 ou 3, mas poderia coloca *C IN (1,2,3)*, combinando inclusive com operadores lógicos, exemplo *C = 1 AND B = 2*. Portanto, se o registro que está sendo avaliado retornar Verdadeiro, soma-se 1, caso contrário, soma-se 0 (o que não faz diferença na soma). Enfim, é uma maneira de contar os registros utilizando o SUM e não o COUNT(*).